# javascript change css by tag index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in my code i have around 11 image tags , all of them have an id of "#bigimage"
i want to change the style of an image on each click on a specific button for the specific image
meaning on the first click changing the #bigimage [0]
second click changing the #bigimage [1]
etc...

this is what i did:

```
<script>
//click event
$('.jssora05r').click(function() {
var abc=$('#bigimag').length;
var ind=0
$("#bigimag").index(ind).css("display", "block !important");
ind++;
});
</script>
```

it's not working, could someone help me?

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements with the same id.  Ids are unique to a page view.  You should change it to a class and use it that way.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, by saying "and use it that way" you mean like in my example above?

Comment: Insead of <img id="bigimag"> it would be <img class="bigimag"> and then the selector would change to $('.bigimag')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just declare `ind` out side of the click event

also you need to change that id selector to some class selector and add same class to all images

```
<script>
var int = 0;

//click event
$('.jssora05r').click(function() {
   // change id to some class
    var abc=$('.someclass').length;

    $(".someclass").index(ind).css("display", "block !important");
    ind++;
});
```

Comment: $('#bigimag').length would always be 1